# Create patterns to detect the occurrence of sequences so that you can restrict in which cases to replace the detected substrings in the input string

Tags: python, string, replace

These are the **input string examples**:

```py
#example 1.1
colloquial_hour = "Hola nos vemos a las diez y veinte a m, ten en cuenta que al amanecer tendremos que estar despiertos, porque debemos estar alli a eso de nueve a m o las diez y cuarto a m"
#example 1.2
colloquial_hour = "A mi me parece entre las 10 15 am y las 11 a m, o a las 15 a m aunque quizas a medianoche este bien a eso de las 00:00 a m"
#example 1.3
colloquial_hour = "Puede que a las 10 am. Hay 10 a medias, a m mmm... creo que en 10 estarian para terminar a las 11:00 hs a m 11:59 a m"
#example 1.4
colloquial_hour = "Amediados a mediados del 30 antes de y dia; me parace que hay que estar en casa. Medianamente a, mediados de las 05 a m o cerca de 6 a m."
```

I have tried with a simple replacement, but I think that the cases must be further restricted with a regex pattern so that unwanted replacements are not made...

```py
colloquial_hour = colloquial_hour.replace('a m', 'am ')
```

, and to be able to obtain this string as output...

the **correct output** for each of these examples:

```py
#example 1.1
colloquial_hour = "Hola nos vemos a las diez y veinte am, ten en cuenta que al amanecer tendremos que estar despiertos, porque debemos estar alli a eso de nueve am o las diez y cuarto am"
#example 1.2
colloquial_hour = "A mi me parece entre las 10 15 am y las 11 am, o a las 15 am aunque quizas a medianoche este bien a eso de las 00:00 am"
#example 1.3
colloquial_hour = "Puede que a las 10 am. Hay 10 a medias, a m mmm... creo que en 10 estarian para terminar a las 11:00 hs am 11:59 am"
#example 1.4
colloquial_hour = "Amediados a mediados del 30 antes de y dia; me parace que hay que estar en casa. Medianamente a, mediados de las 05 am o cerca de 6 am."
```

In this case, the pseudo-pattern is:
some number **"a m" to replace with the string "am"** one or more empty spaces, a period, a comma or directly the end of the string

Cases should also be considered where there may be incompletely written schedules where "am" would be preceded by `":"`, `" :"`, `": "`, `" hs"`, `"hs"`, `"hs "`, `" h.s. "`, `"h.s."`, `"h.s. "`,  `" h.s"`, `"h.s"` or `"h.s "` , for example,

```py
input_t = "a las 12: a m"
output = "a las 12: am"

input_t = "a las 12 : a m"
output = "a las 12 : am"

input_t = "a las 12 hs a m"
output = "a las 12 hs am"

input_t = "a las 12:hs a m"
output = "a las 12:hs am"

input_t = "a las 12: hs a m"
output = "a las 12: hs am"

input_t = "a las 12hsa m"
output = "a las 12hs am"

input_t = "a las 12h.sa m"
output = "a las 12h.s am"

input_t = "a las 12 h.sa m"
output = "a las 12 h.s am"

input_t = "a las 12 h.s.a m"
output = "a las 12 h.s. am"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first part I made this regex:

```
out = re.sub(r"([0-9][0-9]\W)a m(\W|\b)", r"\1am\2", colloquial_hour)
```

It change the "a m" for "am" keeping whatever was before and after.

For the "hs" or "h.s" I did this:

```
out = re.sub(r"(hs|h.s)(\.)?\W*a m(\W|\b)", r"\1\2 am\3", out)
```

It search for "hs", "h.s" before "a m". You can combine both regex, they are pretty similar or use them sequentially.

Let me know if there is any problem.

Comment: In the string that contain **"as, a m mmm... creo que"**  I had a problem with this part, since this "am" should not be replaced by "am" (in the example 3)

Comment: I see, I think I fixed it

Comment: thanks but i found another problem with the string **"terminar a las 11:00 hs a m 11:59 am"**, because it doesn't replace "a m" with "am" like this **"terminar a las 11:00 hs am 11:59 am"**